# Request becomes "undefined" when it is itearated

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

This is a weird fact. In my API REST im working on a specific section, it takes an array of objects, each of them have inside the code (_id) of an specific item and other stuff, but the important thing here is the _id.

Cool, the object is sent vía RAW request, it looks like:

```
"items": [{ "code": "item-code-001", ... }]
```

Im using **nodejs, express and coffeescript** to work, so, my code to take this is:

```
client     = req.body["client_data"]
items      = req.body.items


for i in items
      Item.findOne()
        .where '_id'
        .equals i.code
        .exec (err, item) ->
          if err
            res.json new Internal(err.stack, err.message)
          else if not item
            res.json new NotFound("No existe #{i.code}, y es requerido")
          else if item.existencia < i.cantidad
            res.json new Forbidden("Cantidad #{i.cantidad} supera a la existencia")
          else
            next()
```

The strange thing about all this is that when I do these iterations, tells me he can not read the "code" property of undefined.

Is weird because when i log "items" it returns me the complete array, and the `for in` loop of coffeescript takes the values and not the indexes, so `i` is not the index but the value: `console.log i // {"code": "item-code-1", ...}`.

Any idea? Watching the coffee documentation i dont get my error, and in standalone little tests the code works well (with plain arrays of objects).

Answer (score 1):

To access the value in the loop, it's necessary indicate the array and the index in `for each`. See this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/snj0zw5c/

In your case, alter the stack of code:

```
[...]     
.where '_id'
            .equals items[i].code
[..]
```

Comment: Well, i discovered that is possible to add another iterator to the for in loop on coffe: `for v, i in array` and take the "v" (value) and "i" (index) separated. So yep, i solved the problem.

Thanks!